# Pensarlo vs. pienso?

Tags: vocabulario, verbos, tiempos-verbales

Since the song "Despacito" is so popular now, I decided to look at [the lyrics](http://www.metrolyrics.com/despacito-lyrics-luis-fonsi.html).

One word I didn't know was "pensarlo". I looked it up and it means "I think", coming from the verb pensar, "to think". However, the "yo" conjugation of "pensar" is "pienso", which means "I think". What's the difference between "pensarlo" and "pienso"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Pienso** is *to think* as you correctly said.

> Yo pienso = I think

But **Pensarlo** is *to think about it*

> Déjame pensarlo = let me think about it
>
> Yo voy a pensarlo antes de tomar una decisión = I'll think about it before making a decision.

and in the case of the lyrics...

> Solo con pensarlo se acelera el pulso = Just thinking about it my heart rate rises.

<sub>A better version of the lyrics [here](https://genius.com/11688210)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Wanting to add something to DGaleano's answer, any verb followed by -lo/-la/-los/-las is related to the subject/action which is being talking about.
For example,

> Como no tengo tiempo para comprar ropa hoy, voy a **comprarla** mañana.

In this case, "voy a comprarla" means the same as "la compraré" or "I'm going to buy it".